# How do I iterate ms-access reports in .net using Object model

Tags: ms-access

How to enumerate MS Access reports in windows dot net application.

I have a listbox that should show the available reports in a MS Access db. Tried following code, but it did not show anything.

```
oAccess = GetAccessDBObject(DBLocation);                              
Reports accessReports = oAccess.Reports; // oAccess.Reports.Count = 0!!! No data comes out here!!!
```

How do I iterate ms-access reports in .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this example in C# and it works:

```
        Access.Application oAccess = new Access.Application();
        oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"D:\tmp\dbtest.mdb", false, "");
        Access.AllObjects reports = oAccess.CurrentProject.AllReports;
        Console.WriteLine(reports.Count);
        foreach (Access.AccessObject report in reports)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(report.Name);
        }
```

(you have to add a reference to *Microsoft Access Object Library* to your project, of course.)

Comment: Here you can't type cast to 'Reports' class!! How to overcome?

Comment: Edited answer according to your question.

Comment: Note that this solution requires that Access be installed on the system.

Comment: Hi, how to get data from 'reports' object here?

Answer (score 1):

As Tony Toews mentions, if Access is not installed, you can't automate. This SQL will work on any system:

```
  SELECT MSysObjects.Name
  FROM MSysObjects
  WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=-32764))
  ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

However, note that permissions can get in the way of accessing the Jet/ACE system tables.

Also, there's not much you can do with a list of Access reports without Access! But I thought it was good for completeness to mention this.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ( Reports rprt in oAccess.Reports )
{

 listbox.items.Add(rprt);
}
```

// Disclaimer: Wrote it off the top of my head, don't know if a Reports object has a name property to show it's name in your listbox.

Comment: According to the docs, this will only give you Reports that are already open; see my answer how to get a collection of every report.